# React website slow to load - Is it due to many static assets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, server-side, client-side

I'm ML pro getting up to speed on frontend. So I added a bunch of fixed assets like images and stuff like that in the assets folder for React and I feel like my website is slow.

Do you think the fixed assets, the images I added is the reason for the slowness?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you could cache them, and remove some large images or files.

Comment: Hi zixuan, what do you mean? I'm not very strong in frontend. I remember someone before told me not to worry about fixed assets because it only renders when used? Is this true.

Comment: You could take a look at this:https://raygun.com/blog/critical-path-for-asset-loading/

Comment: Hi Zixuan, so are you saying that fixed assets do slow down a React site? Cause someone before said that it doesnt, and I shouldnt worry about adding alot of fixed asset images. Thank you.

Comment: What does the profiler look like in the dev tools (lighthouse/performace)? Network panel, what is taking forever to load?

Comment: Hi epascarello, I'm looking into lighhouse and what your saying right now. It's this site: https://discover.doveltech.com/ Thanks much for the comment.

Comment: The images you have are Megabytes in size which are quite big, you should run them through an image compression tool first like imagemin to reduce the image size, and make sure they're resized correctly so you dont ship images that are too big in size in comparison to what you render in the img tag's width/height. You can use smaller image types aswell in comparison to your current png image like jpeg or svg

Lazyloading your javascript and css would be nice too

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all assets slow down your website loading time since they have to be downloaded in case they have not been cached in the first place.

You should look into **code-splitting** your app [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html). that way you can load your JS code in chunks and only when needed. Second thing is that you should **optimize your assets**, **your hero image takes up 1.7 MB** which is really a lot for someone using a slow internet connection (3g). Also, someone already mentioned in the comments to look into the **critical rendering path**, no need to load a footer if your user is going to be looking at a pretty hero image. :)